# How to reply to an external recipient in Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

I am having a slight problem with Google Groups - this being sending an email to an external recipient.

Situation is as below:

1. an external party (call it EXT) sends email to provided Google group email address;
2. as Google group is set with permission to publish = Internet, an email from EXT is converted to a new topic which appears on Google Groups board;
3. when doing a reply to EXT topic as a Google group member, an email is being posted to all other group members, which is correct;
4. however EXT is not sent an email with reply and does not get any message.

I am keen to know if getting replies by EXT is possible?
Am I missing something obvious? Or is there some permission which needs to be set?

---

Thanks a lot for responding Ruben,

So to re-cap:

1. if any member of a google group posts (replies) to a new topic a reply is only sent internally to its group members; EXT will not receive an update;
2. if a group member clicks (reply privately to an author) - EXT will receive a reply.

There are two downsides I see here:

- private reply is not visible in group members topic breakdown - so google group members (incl. person who sent reply privately) don't see it:

[image: settings]
[image: no reply content visible]

- private response is always sent (as a user) instead of (on behalf of) group name, which will quickly lead to confusion;

Moreover, if EXT replies to a reply - it gets created as a new topic instead of arranging into an existing topic and sent only to memebr of a group instead to a group email.

[image]

My aim is to create a two-way communication group between Google Group members and external party (not a google domain) and I have a feeling I am missing something obvious to make it work right or Google Groups is not designed as a "ticket" platform.

Your further help is much appreciated, unfortunately Google's Wikis does not answer my questions :)

Comment: What do you by Google's Wikis? By the way, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Google Groups can't not be used to have both public and private messages archived in the group as there aren't privacy settings by post / topic. I suggest you to ask for a software recommendation in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

---

You have to use a Google Account and the Groups should be set to allow replying to post author.

1. Go to manage group settings
2. Open **Posting permissions**
3. In the **Reply to author** select who can reply privately to the author of topic
4. Click **Save**

[image]

Related

- [Create a group & choose group settings](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464926?hl=en&)
- [Create & respond to posts](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1046523?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks again Ruben, much appreciated.